# Initialize own type with string

Tags: c#, indexing, instantiation

Is it possible to instantiate a variable like following example

```
OwnType variable = "String";
```

instead of

```
OwnType variable = new OwnType("String");
```

Maybe with a index field in OwnType or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) from `string` to `OwnType`. This would let you hide the call of operator `new` in the operator:

```
public static implicit operator OwnType(string str)
{
    return new OwnType(str);
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/9Rivgb).

Comment: That's so easy? Thank you :)